# Looking to add an AI player in Python Pong using Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I can't seem to get my AI pong paddle to work in Python 3.7.1. I'll admit that I'm new to this so the fix may be easier than I'm making it.

I've tried various forms of adjusting the loops but i think i'm missing something small that plays a big role in the code's processing.

```
import turtle

# build window
win = turtle.Screen()

# window title/color/size
win.title("csc2280 Project")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=800, height=800)
win.tracer(0)

# user paddle
user_paddle = turtle.Turtle()
# user paddle build
user_paddle.shape('square')
user_paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
user_paddle.speed('fastest')
user_paddle.color("white")
# user paddle position
user_paddle.penup()
user_paddle.goto(-350, 0)

# ai paddle
AI_paddle = turtle.Turtle()
# ai paddle build
AI_paddle.shape('square')
AI_paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
AI_paddle.speed('fastest')
AI_paddle.color('white')
#ai paddle position
AI_paddle.penup()
AI_paddle.goto(350, 0)
AI_paddle.speed = 15

# ball 
ball = turtle.Turtle()
ball.speed(0)
# ball shape
ball.shape('circle')
ball.color('white')
# ball position
ball.penup()
ball.goto(0, 0)
# ball movement
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

# Pen
pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.speed(0)
pen.shape("square")
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.hideturtle()
pen.goto(0, 260)
pen.write("Player A: 0  Player B: 0", align = "center", font = ("Calibri", 24, "normal"))

# Keeping Score
score_p1 = 0
score_p2 = 0

# move user paddle up and down

# user paddle up
def user_paddle_up():
    y = user_paddle.ycor()
    y += 20
    user_paddle.sety(y)

# user paddle down
def user_paddle_down():
    y = user_paddle.ycor()
    y -= 20
    user_paddle.sety(y)

# actually moving the paddle
win.listen()
win.onkeypress(user_paddle_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(user_paddle_down, "Down")

AI_paddle.forward(AI_paddle.speed)
y = AI_paddle.ycor()
if y < -300 or y > 300:
    AI_paddle.speed *= -1
```

I think the issue is right in here somewhere.

```
# game loop
while True:
    win.update()

# moving the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # create border
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1

        # updating score
        score_p1 += 1    
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_p1, score_p2), align = "center", font = ("Calibri", 24, "normal"))

    if ball.xcor() < -400:
        ball.goto(0,0)
        ball.dx *= -1

        # updating score
        score_p2 += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_p1, score_p2), align = "center", font = ("Calibri", 24, "normal"))


    # paddle/ball interaction
    if (ball.xcor() > 340 and ball.xcor() < 350) and (ball.ycor() < AI_paddle.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > AI_paddle.ycor() -40):
        ball.setx(340)
        ball.dx *= -1

    if (ball.xcor() < -340 and ball.xcor() > -350) and (ball.ycor() < user_paddle.ycor() + 40 and ball.ycor() > user_paddle.ycor() -40):
        ball.setx(-340)
        ball.dx *= -1
```

Any help would be super appreciated as this is my final project for the semester and this is literally the only thing holding me up.

Comment: You haven’t described any specific problem or asked any question here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I found with your AI player is that this code is in the wrong place:

```
AI_paddle.forward(AI_paddle.speed)
y = AI_paddle.ycor()
if y < -300 or y > 300:
    AI_paddle.speed *= -1
```

It's just before the main loop so it only gets executed once.  It should be *inside* the main loop, e.g. as the last item.

I found your game difficult to play so I've tweaked some things below to make it more playable and I've made the fix I described above:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

FONT = ("Calibri", 24, "normal")

# move user paddle up and down

# user paddle up
def user_paddle_up():
    y = user_paddle.ycor() + 20
    user_paddle.sety(y)

# user paddle down
def user_paddle_down():
    y = user_paddle.ycor() - 20
    user_paddle.sety(y)

# build window
win = Screen()

# window title/color/size
win.title("csc2280 Project")
win.bgcolor("black")
win.setup(width=800, height=800)
win.tracer(0)

# user paddle
user_paddle = Turtle('square')
# user paddle build
user_paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
user_paddle.color("white")
# user paddle position
user_paddle.penup()
user_paddle.setx(-350)

# AI paddle
AI_paddle = Turtle('square')
# AI paddle build
AI_paddle.shapesize(stretch_wid=5, stretch_len=1)
AI_paddle.color('white')
# AI paddle position
AI_paddle.penup()
AI_paddle.setx(350)
AI_paddle.speed = 10

# ball
ball = Turtle('circle')
# ball shape
ball.color('white')
# ball position
ball.penup()
# ball movement
ball.dx = 2
ball.dy = 2

# Court
court = Turtle(visible=False)
court.color("white")
court.penup()
court.goto(-400, -300)
court.pendown()
court.forward(800)
court.penup()
court.goto(-400, 300)
court.pendown()
court.forward(800)
court.penup()

# Pen
pen = Turtle(visible=False)
pen.color("white")
pen.penup()
pen.sety(325)
pen.write("Player A: 0  Player B: 0", align="center", font=("Calibri", 24, "normal"))

# Keeping Score
score_p1 = 0
score_p2 = 0

# actually moving the paddle
win.onkeypress(user_paddle_up, "Up")
win.onkeypress(user_paddle_down, "Down")
win.listen()

# game loop
while True:
    win.update()

    # moving the ball
    ball.setx(ball.xcor() + ball.dx)
    ball.sety(ball.ycor() + ball.dy)

    # enforce boundaries
    if ball.ycor() > 290:
        ball.sety(290)
        ball.dy *= -1
    elif ball.ycor() < -290:
        ball.sety(-290)
        ball.dy *= -1

    if ball.xcor() > 390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

        # updating score
        score_p1 += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_p1, score_p2), align="center", font=FONT)

    elif ball.xcor() < -390:
        ball.goto(0, 0)
        ball.dx *= -1

        # updating score
        score_p2 += 1
        pen.clear()
        pen.write("Player A: {}  Player B: {}".format(score_p1, score_p2), align="center", font=FONT)

    # paddle/ball interaction
    if (330 < ball.xcor() < 370) and (AI_paddle.ycor() - 60 < ball.ycor() < AI_paddle.ycor() + 60):
        ball.setx(330)
        ball.dx = - abs(ball.dx)

    if (-370 < ball.xcor() < -330) and (user_paddle.ycor() - 60 < ball.ycor() < user_paddle.ycor() + 60):
        ball.setx(-330)
        ball.dx = abs(ball.dx)

    y = AI_paddle.ycor() + AI_paddle.speed
    if y < -240 or y > 240:
        AI_paddle.speed *= -1
    AI_paddle.sety(y)
```

Good luck with making your AI player smarter!